# On a Chinese visa application, how strict are the hotel detail requirements?

Tags: visas, china, proof-of-accommodation

I'm a British citizen applying for a Chinese tourist visa for a trip of 8 days, flying into and out of Beijing from the UK.

The application form asks for hotel details for the entire trip, but the itinerary isn't finalised yet.

Do I need to have a complete, accurate, and final itinerary before I can get the visa?  Or can I submit a best guess as to where I'll be staying?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are not held to your specific itinerary. Just write your current plan, and if that changes, so be it.

Answer (score 4):

You can just put your most likely destination(s).  They may also ask for flight reservations but the agency I used said outright book, print, cancel, which is what I did.

As a foreigner, the hotel will register you with the local authorities automatically so the address on the visa application really is a formality.  And if you're applying for a multiple-entry visa, it's a complete non-issue.

Enjoy!

Comment: `book, print, cancel` - remember China has a lot of human resources and big data in play... In 2 years this hack will not work any more :)